# without any memory issue- calling asynchronously a method repetedly after delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, grand-central-dispatch

How to call a **specific method asynchronously**  **with delay repeatedly** in an efficient way, so that there is **minimal amount of memory usage** without affecting app performance.

I know we can directly do that in `dispatch_async` but not sure how it works or thus is it an  efficent way of approach.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: it depend , what kind of method we talking about here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dispatch timers. Here's a trivial example that calls a block every 2 seconds:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    dispatch_source_t timer;
}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    NSTimeInterval delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    NSTimeInterval leeway = delayInSeconds * 0.1;
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC, leeway * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
        NSLog(@"Timer called");
    });
    dispatch_resume(timer);
}

@end
```

As for memory usage, that's up to the method you call. The memory required to set up the timer itself is negligible.